# How to substitute JavaScript variable into a JSPath expression

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that reads in a JSON file, and retrieves information by matching values with a user input string. In order to navigate the JSON file I'm using JSPath however I can't work out how to use the string variable that the function is passed in the JSPath predicate.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
function retrieveCategoryWinners(query) {
  var category = query
  var jsonDoc = $.getJSON("nobel.json")
  var winners = JSPath.apply('.prizes{.category === $query}.laureates', jsonDoc,
      {query: category})
```

A snippet of the JSON file:

```
{
    "prizes": [
        {
            "year": "2017",
            "category": "physics",
            "laureates": [
                {
                    "id": "941",
                    "firstname": "Rainer",
                    "surname": "Weiss",
                    "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
                    "share": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "942",
                    "firstname": "Barry C.",
                    "surname": "Barish",
                    "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
                    "share": "4"
                },
                {
                    "id": "943",
                    "firstname": "Kip S.",
                    "surname": "Thorne",
                    "motivation": "\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"",
                    "share": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
```

So, for example, if the query argument was "physics", JSPath would return the 'laureates' array. Substituting the variable into the predicate doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable substitution is wrong . Try it with a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this.

```
  var winners = JSPath.apply(`.prizes{.category === "${category}"}.laureates`, js,
            {query: category})
```